# Access Value of an Object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this state which is store in a single object, the subject are the keys. 

[image]

My code, I need to pass the corresponding array to **Timeline** component,(Timeline component will handle the mapping of array that will be pass) any idea?

```
   Object.keys(newTimelineData).map(title => (
      <Timeline
        chartId={title}
        timelineData={title.array} // array should be here
        {...timelineChartProps}
      />
    )
```

Comment: if `data` is your object and `title` is something like `A5 Maths` then `data["A5 Maths"]` will return the A5 Maths array. Or in your case `newTimelineData.title` should work

Comment: @Craicerjack, damn, that was fast. thanks! could you comment so I can upvote it up?

Comment: Once you get it working just fill in the answer yourself and accept it or if the answer below is good, accept that. Its all good. Thanks though

Comment: I'll take note of  that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Object.keys(newTimelineData).map(title => (
      <Timeline
        chartId={title}
        timelineData={state[title]} // array should be here
        {...timelineChartProps}
      />
    )
```

Comment: craicerjack got it first, but gonna upvote you for the help.